# Edit option in Deal for Wallet in Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

So far i am developing the Windows Phone application that make an Wallet API to work for Wallet in Windows Phone 8. Normally we can use `Deal` object to add the deals into the Wallet application. But in every attempt, added deal does not have an option to edit. However if it is added through build in Wallet app, Obviously it has an Edit option. I am cracking my head for this problem for a long time. Could you please any one can help me to enable the Edit option through `Deal` API ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's intentional. Think about the zen of a wallet. When a user inputs a deal manually it doesn't mean anything to anyoe but the user. When your app creates a deal it means something to other people (to cashier looking at it, the machine scanning the barcode, etc). So it's important your deals don't get changed by the user.

Your locally stored deals on the phone are only a facade to deals stored on the server. So if you want to update those , you'll need to create a WalletAgent, pull data from a remote source and update those deals in the background.

Here's a code sample of a trivial WalletAgent that always marks all your wallet items as "Attention needed". Obviously this would be a good place to query a remote web service and update your WalletItem properties.

```
public class myWalletAgent : WalletAgent
{
    protected override void OnRefreshData(RefreshDataEventArgs args)
    {
        foreach (WalletItem item in args.Items)
        {
            item.SetUserAttentionRequiredNotification(true);
        }

        base.OnRefreshData(args);
        NotifyComplete();
    }
}
```